# Cannot convert value of type 'UserFile' to expected argument 'User'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am making an iOS app using Swift 3 and Firebase. I keep getting the error "Cannot convert value of type 'UserFile' to expected argument 'User'". Here is my code:

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth


class UserAPI {

    var REF_USERS = Database.database().reference().child("users")

    var CURRENT_USER: User? {
        if let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser {
            return currentUser
        }
        return nil
    }

    var CURRENT_USER_ID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

    var REF_CURRENT_USER: DatabaseReference? {
        guard let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser else {
            return nil
        }
        return REF_USERS.child(currentUser.uid)
    }

    func observeCurrentUser(completion: @escaping (User) -> Void) {
        guard let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser else {
            return
        }

        REF_USERS.child(currentUser.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
            if let postDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
                let user = UserFile.transformUser(postDictionary: postDictionary)
                completion(user)        //Cannot convert value of type 'UserFile' to expected argument 'User'
            }
        })
    }

    func observeUser(withID uid:String, completion: @escaping (User) -> Void) {
        REF_USERS.child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
            if let postDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
                let user = UserFile.transformUser(postDictionary: postDictionary)
                completion(user)        //Cannot convert value of type 'UserFile' to expected argument 'User'
            }
        })
    }

}
```

'UserFile' is another Swift file and here is the code for that:

```
import Foundation

class UserFile {
    var email: String?
    var profileImageURL: String?
    var username: String?
}

extension UserFile {

    static func transformUser(postDictionary: [String: Any]) -> UserFile {
        let user = UserFile()

        user.email = postDictionary["email"] as? String
        user.profileImageURL = postDictionary["profileImageURL"] as? String
        user.username = postDictionary["username"] as? String

        return user
    }

}
```

I have no idea of what I should do. Any ideas?

Comment: Your functions shows that `completion` is of type user: `func observeCurrentUser(completion: @escaping (User) -> Void) {` and you're passing `UserFile` into it. Why not change the completion type to `UserFile`, like this? `(completion: @escaping (UserFile) -> Void) `?

Comment: It worked... If you put this as an answer I'll upvote and mark it as the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your functions shows that completion is of type user: `func observeCurrentUser(completion: @escaping (User) -> Void) {`and you're passing `UserFile` into it.

Change the completion type to `UserFile`, like this:(`completion: @escaping (UserFile) -> Void)`